# Need help on protractor setup from scratch using Visual Studio 2012/2015

Tags: angularjs, selenium, visual-studio-2012, protractor

I am a newbie as far as angular apps E2E testing is concerned. I have been searching for a proper solution since two weeks and couldn't find a concrete solution as to how to implement protractor for testing angular+non-angular applications using visual studio as the IDE (I Strictly want to use Visual Studio not any other IDE).

So far i know that i need to install node.js for visual studio and create a blank node.js console application within visual studio. Apart from this i have a few questions :

1) How to Configure my protractor tests in a way that i can use selenium-webdriver locators?
2) How to add a reporting feature in my tests? I need screenshots of failed specs.
3) How to run my tests? Do i always have to open the command prompt by right clicking on the project folder -> Open command prompt here 
4) How do i Integrate this setup with tfs?

Please help me with this.I really had a tough time figuring out from where to start!

Comment: This is way too broad. It seems you haven't even grasped the basics of WebDriver in two weeks, yet you have a number of very specific and disconnected demands. I really suggest you start at the beginning with Protractor and WebDriver and then come back with more specific questions one you have a good grounding.

Comment: You have to create a node project to get this accomplished as protractor is a javascript/node solution.   Use js reporting solutions for the reports like Karma, You don't always have to open command prompt, but that means you need to call the Node cmd from VS via configuration the project properties.  To integrate into TFS simply check the project in just like C# solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer for your general question:

I have a [Protractor example project on GitHub](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor_example) that should help answer many of your questions. Once you get a general understanding of how Protractor works, you should be able to search/ask more specific questions here on stack.